# Changing table division color on mouse over in html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a table division change color when the mouse goes over it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<td class="mydiv"><a href = "stained_glass.html" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor="#000000"">Stained Glass</a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this css:

```
td.mydiv:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CH7Sh/2/).

Comment: i never knew you could use `:hover` on something other than an `<a>` tag :o

Comment: @khaverim now you know :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using simply css:

```
.mydiv:hover{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

The :hover selector is used to select elements when go over them with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Сould just use css, like in this example:

```
.mydiv:hover { background-color:#000000; }
```